# How can I uninstall a startup item in Mac OS X 10.5.8? Where is the "Accounts" preference pane?

Tags: macos, osx-leopard, system-preferences, login-items

I use OS X 10.5.8. How do I prevent some programs from opening upon startup?

I have tried to find the "Account" Preference Pane on my iMac, but cannot find it even by trying to find it from previous answers given to other users with iMacs.

Answer (score 2):

In OS X (Leopard) these are called *Login Items*.

The setting should definitely be in your *System Preferences*. To access them, click the  button and click *System Preferences…*. Look for the *Accounts* pane, it's the one bottom left, right under "System".

[image]

There, click on *Login Items*.

[image]

Just click <kbd>–</kbd> for those items you want to delete.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not in the login items....

Right Click on the Dock icon for the application, and check to see if "Open at Login" is turned on.  (It maybe in the options menu for the Dock item)